# Is spacetime defined mathematically without using $c$ speed?

Tags: spacetime, speed-of-light, metric-tensor, conventions, dimensional-analysis

Is there a mathematical definition of spacetime that does not use $c$ speed as a conversion factor or involve the spacetime interval?  If not why?

Comment: This probably depends a lot on what you mean by "definition" and "spacetime." There is Galilean spacetime, which doesn't have a metric. Most relativists work in units where $c=1$, so no factors of $c$ appear.

Comment: and c=1 causes dimensional analysis problems. eg. e=m

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a mathematical definition of spacetime that does not use c speed as a conversion factor or involve the spacetime interval?

Yes, absolutely! The quantity $c$ really is just a units-conversion factor. If we use a coordinate system $t,x,y,z$ with $t$ expressed in units of time and $x,y,z$ expressed in units of length, then we need to use $c$ in some equations in order to equalize the units, like in this equation for the proper time $\tau$:
$$
   d\tau^2 = dt^2 - \frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{c^2}.
\tag{1}
$$
(Here, $d\tau$ is the proper-time increment along one piece of the object's history, and $dt,dx,dy,dz$ are the corresponding coordinate-increments.) But we can also use a coordinate system $t,x,y,z$ (I'm recycling the letters) with all four coordinates expressed in the *same* units. Then equation (1) becomes
$$
   d\tau^2 = dt^2 - (dx^2+dy^2+dz^2).
\tag{2}
$$
In fact, this is the way physicists *usually* do things in general relativity (as Ben Crowell's comment said). We can either express $\tau,t,x,y,z$ all in units of time, or we could express them all in units of length.

The justification for this is essentially the same as the justification for expressing both vertical distances and horizontal distances in the same units. We *could* express vertical distances in meters and express horizontal distances in feet, but then we would need to include an awkward units-conversion factor in the equation for the length-increment $d\ell$ in 3-d space, like this:
$$
 d\ell^2 = \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{a^2}+dz^2
\tag{3}
$$
where $a$ is the conversion factor that relates horizontal- and vertical-distance units. Thanks to rotational symmetry, though, it is more natural to use the *same* units for both types of distance — especially because *most* distances are neither vertical nor horizontal, but somewhere in between. So we might as well use the same units for both and just write the distance equation like this:
$$
 d\ell^2 = dx^2+dy^2+dz^2.
\tag{4}
$$
The difference between equations (1) and (2) is the same as the difference between equations (3) and (4). In the case of equations (1) and (2),  **Lorentz symmetry** is the reason why (2) is more natural than (1), juse like rotational symmetry is the reason why (4) is more natural than (3). Lorentz symmetry mixes the coordinate $t$ with the coordinates $x,y,z$, just like rotational symmetry mixes the coordinates $x,y$ with the coordinate $z$.